# Assigning a predicate variable instead of a lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicate, func

The following textbook Join query runs fine:

```
var list = from family in db.Families.Where(f => !f.isDeleted)
  join member in db.Members.Where(m => !m.isDeleted)
  on family.Id equals member.FamilyID
  select new { family = family.LastName, member = member.DisplayName };
```

`list` is a `IQueryable: {Microsoft.FrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>>}` and I can call `list.ToList()`.

However, instead of using a lambda, if I use a predicate in the first `Where` as follows:

```
Predicate<Family> query = f => !f.isDeleted;
var list = from family in db.Families.Where(new Func<Family, bool>(query))
  join member in db.Members.Where(m => !m.isDeleted)
  on family.Id equals member.FamilyID
  select new { family = family.LastName, member = member.DisplayName };
```

then `list` becomes a `[IEnumerable]: {System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__105<Family, Member, short, <>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>>}` and the Results View throws a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.".

I couldn't reproduce it anymore but I am certain sometimes the Results View throws a "Data is null" exception.

I need to make my filter a variable as the exact filter required depends on some other conditions. Why does using a `Predicate` assignment cause the type of `list` to be different, and how do I fix the error?

Comment: You are calling different overloads of `Where`. You should pass a `Expression<Func<Family, bool>>` in there, not a `Func<Family, bool>`.

Comment: How do I do it? I changed `query` to `Expression<Predicate<Family>> query = f => !f.isDeleted;`, but am unable to drop it into `.Where(query)`.

Comment: Read my comment again please. I did not say `Expression<Predicate<Family>>`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I had the wrong understanding `Predicate<T>` is the same as `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: It is conceptually the same but they are still delegates of different types, even though they have the same signature. And Where expects specifically Func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling two very different overloads of `Where`. In the first code snippet, you are calling:

[`Where<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,Boolean>>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Where__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___)

This overload translates your lambda expression into a SQL query and runs it on the database.

And in the second code snippet, you are calling

[`Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)

The second overload is the LINQ to Objects `Where`, which doesn't know about your database at all. It works with all `IEnumerable<T>`s.

You should create an `Expression<Func<Family, bool>>` and pass it in:

```
Expression<Func<Family, bool>> query = f => !f.isDeleted;
var list = from family in db.Families.Where(query)
    ...
```